The parameterized type of argument was missing in bridge method
class A {
    public void doit(List<String> args) {
    }

    public static class C extends A {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method m = C.class.getMethod("doit", List.class);
        Type ptype = m.getParameters()[0].getParameterizedType();
        System.out.println("type is -> " + ptype);
    }
}

The output is

type is -> interface java.util.List

The doit() method got via reflection was indeed generated by the compiler, and is a synthetic bridge method. However, the parameterized type info String of the argument was missing.
Anybody know why? Maybe a workaround is the make A public if we want to get the parameterized type

The actual type is ParameterizedTypeImpl

That happens because of Type erasure of generics at runtime. The parameterized type only exists at compile type. That's the same reason many libraries needing to find the actual type of things pass an additional parameter with the correct expected class type, pseudocode:
List<T> find(criteria, Class<T> theClass)
List<Customer> = find(..., Customer.class)


But wouldn't List<String> after type erasure still be List<Object> which is the raw type List ?

No, it will be List with no extra info of what List actually accepts

Type erasure  will always happen no matter the super class is public or not. It should not be the reason. When the super class is public, the code within if body could be reached.
